# Creating layout with code

Tags: android

I have problem with creating layout with code. I'm just trying to add a button object on my linear layout but it doesn't create any button.

Here's my onCreate method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);

    Button button = new Button(this);
    button.setText(R.string.click_me);

    layout.addView(button);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}
```

My fragment_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:orientation="vertical" >
```

*****update 1*****

So when adding objects on layout when you have a fragment xml it must be on the fragment class. Thanks to @Fllo for pointing that out. Haven't thought of that way. :(

Here's my updated code in adding the button on PlaceHolderFragment class.

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);


        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.layout);
        Button button = new Button(getActivity());
        button.setText(R.string.click_me);
        layout.addView(button);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you built your views inside **fragment_main.xml** and not **activity_main.xml**.

When you *first* create a new android project, you have these files which are automatically created and opened:

[image]

Then, when you begin, you add views *(e.g: a TextView)* inside `fragment_main.xml` file whereas you tried to do a basically event with this view inside your `Activity` which uses this layout:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // using the activity_main.xml file
```

You cannot run your app or sometimes you have only a white screen, because the views that you tried to call/display are into the wrong layout..

> Solution: **Move all your stuff inside onCreateView method into the Fragment class. Call views and do something in the related fragment and not the parent activity**.

---

Move all your stuff inside your `onCreateView` method into your `PlaceholderFragment` class, as follows:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);  

    // Don't forget to attach your view to the layout
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.layout);
    // Attach the context
    Button button = new Button(getActivity());
    // Add the layout params
    button.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    // Set the text
    button.setText(R.string.click_me);
    // Add the view
    layout.addView(button);  

    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks @Fllo! Yes I'm using a fragment_main.xml. So that's why. I tried first your previous answer but there's an error on instantiating the Button. Then I saw your edited answer right now and added the getActivity method instead of using "this". Can you help me understand why was it like that? And what for is the button.setLayoutParams? Haven't encountered that yet. :)

Comment: @Rhenzzz Does `getActivity()` worked? It's because `this` refer to the context, and on your previous code, it was `MainActivity`. However when you are into a Fragment, you need to attach the context which is the parent Activity. The LayoutParams are the width and height of this views regarding its relative parent.

Comment: Yes @Fllo, `getActivity()` worked. What the diff between `getActivity()` and `getContent()` ? Please check my update if it's correct already. :) Thank you so much!

Comment: @Rhenzzz Same both. Like `this`, `getApplicationContext()`, `NameActivity.this`, etc. However, it's really preferable to use `getActivity()` inside a fragment. - Yes, your edit is right, you got that ;)

Comment: A last thing: when I re-read your question in comments, `getContent` and `getContext` are not equals, be carefull. `getContext` is like `getActivity` whereas `getContent` is used to the `HTTP request`. @Rhenzzz

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this line.

```
button.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your button like this:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layout.addView(button, params);
```